# How to export a single field from a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodump, mongoexport

I want to export a single field from a single collection.
Like *collection name* is *products* and *field name* is *tag*.

All tag will create new collection. I have tried this command:

```
mongodump --host 192.168.1.46 --port 27017 --db myDb --collection products --fields tag -o bson  --out C:\Users\Desktop\tag
```

Comment: Have you got an example of your documents in that `products` collection?

Comment: Can you clarify what `All tag will create new collection.` means? Do you just want to get find all the tags and create a new collection in the same database?

Comment: Hello Kevin, i just wanted to export a single filed from a collection and wanted to create a new collection from those exported field. eg(if products collection has tags field which is string and i just wanted to export all the tags from the products collection and after that exported tags will create a new collection like Tag) hope now you are bettor understand.

Comment: See my answer, should fit that criteria

Answer (score 1):

mongodump doesn't support the selected field's backup. But you can use mongoexport/mongoimport to backup selected fields  as:

```
mongoexport -c test --db testing -f key --out dump.json
```

Comment: sorry what do you mean by i's

Comment: if i use mongoexport istead of mongodump in same command then it's also not working.

Answer (score 1):

So lets start by inserting some products in to our collection:

```
db.products.insertMany([
    { name: 'TV', tags: ['livingroom', 'electronics']},
    { name: 'Radio', tags: ['bedroom', 'electronics']},
    { name: 'Computer', tags: ['bedroom', 'electronics']}
]);

{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("586bae0ec5a9a94b2674943d"),
                ObjectId("586bae0ec5a9a94b2674943e"),
                ObjectId("586bae0ec5a9a94b2674943f")
        ]
}
```

We can now write a simple aggreation query to go though all the documents

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$tags'},
    {$group: {_id: '$tags' }},
    {$out: 'productTags'}
]);
```

The `{$unwind: '$tags'}` will deconstruct the tags array field in to a document for each tag.
Then the `{$group: {_id: '$tags' }}` will group each item and create a new document for each tag.
Then the `{$out: 'productTags'}` will create us a productTags collection with the output of the documents.

now if we query the `productTags` collection we'll get the following output:

```
> db.productTags.find()
{ "_id" : "bedroom" }
{ "_id" : "electronics" }
{ "_id" : "livingroom" }
```